# Move particles without moving particle emitter

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have question about Particles in cocos2d. How can I move particles without moving particle emitter. I want to have such move like in doodle jump(snowing map).I set position type to kCCPositionTypeGrouped and move my particles in this way:

```
CCAction *movePlankton = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.6f position:CGPointMake(planktonEmitter.position.x, planktonEmitter.position.y+distanceToMove)];
    [planktonEmitter runAction:movePlankton];
```

But this move particle emitter too, and after few moves on my screen i haven't any particles.

Can somebody help me with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can only move the emitter. The movement of the particles is an essential aspect of the particle effect itself.

What you can do is:

- use multiple particle emitters, each being responsible for a small aspect of the overall effect
- use sprites for controlled movement